# wpf ComboBox binding in list view

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I have the problem with binding ComboBox in ListView

In ComboBox I need to bind User object from ListDetails object. If I change ComboBox it work, if I open window, binding don't work.
ComboBoxItem is a full list of all existing user from db.

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="colUser" Header="User.Name in ComboBox">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Width="300" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=AlleUser}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=DataContext.User}" 
                            SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

full code you can see in https://github.com/fialo4ka/ListBinding/tree/master
In example I change db loading to some test data

Comment: Also, If I take AlleUser from existing List of users it works perfectly, but if I fill AlleUser with other list, it not work

Comment: What do you mean? You change `AlleUser` after the application has started, but you don't see this changes?

Comment: `AlleUser` is a simple `Dictionary` which doesn't implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`. You have to implement `INotifyPropertyChnaged` on `MainWindow` or use an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @BionicCode Thank you for your replay! I try to change to ObservableCollection... But it still not help to show in comboBox needed value. You can see my changes in gitHub

Answer (score 1):

So... After trying all this answers I still can't see the name of user in loading form, so I found the solution directly put Name to the ComboBox. 
but I still can't understand why all previous solution is not working for me :(

```
        private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((ComboBox)sender).Text = ((ListDetails)((ComboBox)sender).DataContext).User.Name;
        }
```

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox Width="300" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=AlleUser}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding User}" 
                    SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Key.Value"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should bind to the `User` property of the `ListDetails` object:

```
<ComboBox Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}, Path=AlleUser}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding User}" 
          SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Key.Name"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for replay, but the problem is this solution don't work for me :( I try this already!  `indingExpression path error: 'Key' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=Key; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

Comment: @AnAnita: It works just fine for me in your GitHub sample. `Key` is  property of the `KeyValuePair` in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never mix data binding and setting values directly in code-behind.It makes debugging and understanding the code much more difficult for everybody, including yourself. Choose one. I highly recommend data binding. I refactored the code to use data binding only.

The below code works for me. Values are displayed in the `ComboBox`.
If this is still not working as expected, you have to clarify *exactly* what you are doing, what you are expecting and what is actually happening.

Also you usually don't set the `ItemsControl.SelctedValue` property. This property holds the result of the `ItemsControl.SelectedValuePath`, once an item is selected. In your case, when the selected value should be the `User.Name` value, you would need to set the path to `SelectedValuePath="Key.Name"` as the `Key` references the `User` item of the `KeyValuePair` and then `Name` the `User.Name` property. You would bind the `SelectedValue` to a property in your `MainWindow` class, to access it there or to another control, e.g. `TextBlock.Text`.

When reading new data from the database, you first clear the collections and then add the new items. Since you are using an `ObservableCollection` the views will update automatically. Don't set the views directly.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Grid>    
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView Name="lvBezirke" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type main:MainWindow}}, Path=ListDetails}"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="zugeordnete User je Bezirk">
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="colBezirk" Header="Some Data from model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bezirk}" />
          <GridViewColumn x:Name="colUser" Header="User.Name in ComboBox">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Width="300" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type main:MainWindow}}, Path=AlleUser}"                              
                          SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="User.Loginname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Loginname}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="User.Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Name}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="click" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="clear" Click="Button_Click_1" />
    <ListView Name="lvBezirkeClick"
              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type main:MainWindow}}, Path=ListDetailsClick}"
              Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
      <ListView.View>
        <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="zugeordnete User je Bezirk">
          <GridViewColumn Header="Some Data from model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bezirk}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="User.Loginname onClick" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Loginname}" />
          <GridViewColumn Header="User.Name onClick" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding User.Name}" />
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow
{
  public ObservableCollection<ListDetails> ListDetails { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<ListDetails> ListDetailsClick { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<User, string>> AlleUser { get; set; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();  // Always the first line in constructor!

    this.ListDetailsClick = new ObservableCollection<ListDetails>();

    // Initialize ObservableCollection directly
    this.ListDetails = new ObservableCollection<ListDetails>()
    {
      new ListDetails("data 1", new User("1 user", "1")),
      new ListDetails("data 2", new User("8 user", "8")),
      new ListDetails("data 3", new User("5 user", "5")),
    };

    this.AlleUser = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<User, string>>()
    {
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("1 user", "1"), "1") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("2 user", "2"), "2") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("4 user", "3"), "3") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("4 user", "4"), "4") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("5 user", "5"), "5") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("6 user", "6"), "6") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("7 user", "7"), "7") },
      { new KeyValuePair<User, string>(new User("8 user", "8"), "8") },
    };
  }

  private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {

  }

  // Clear and copy
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ListDetailsClick.Clear();
    this.ListDetails.ToList().ForEach(this.ListDetailsClick.Add);
  }

  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    this.ListDetailsClick.Clear();
  }
}
```